# I have imported a function, but cant use the variable from it

Tags: python

So I have this as an imported file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import time

def soupIt(URL, osztaly, pls):
    global full
    global noedit
    global ft
    global ftfull
    global eur
    global eurfull
    global dollar
    global dollarfull
    content = requests.get(URL)
    soup = bs(content.text, 'html.parser')
    do = soup.find_all(pls, class_ = osztaly)[0].get_text()
    noedit = do.strip()
    do = noedit.replace('.', '')
    do = do.replace(',', '')
    do = do.replace(' ', '')
    do = do.replace('  ', '')
    do = do.replace('Ft', '')
    do = do.replace('$', '')
    full = do.replace('€', '')
    ft = noedit + " Ft"
    ftfull = full + " Ft"
    eur = noedit + " €"
    eurfull = full + " €"
    dollar = noedit + " $"
    dollarfull = full + " $"
```

and I try to use this in the file which I tried `soupIt()`

```
from scrhelp import soupIt
soupIt("https://www.emag.hu/aoc-gaming-monitor-ips-23-8-full-hd-1-ms-144hz-freesync-dp-hdmi-fekete-24g2u-bk/pd/D0HVSGBBM/",'product-new-price', "")
print(full)
```

and it gives me the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\Donát\Programozás\Phyton\webscraper\apitest.py", line 3, in 
> print(full)
> NameError: name 'full' is not defined

and I tried to set it global `full` global in the file where I try to use it, but it doesn't work, and I'm new to python.

Comment: globals dont are available across imports

Comment: If you need a value from a function, ideally that value should be explicitly returned from the function. Then you aren't needing to worry about scope or globals.

Comment: @Andreas then do I just put the result in a file, and then pull it from there?

Comment: @dobos 90 I tried something very similar when I started with Python. I highly recomend using classes for this, it is a bit more difficult tto wrap your head around at first but much much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only imported the function `soupIt` into your namespace.  The variable `full` is only global to the module.  You also need to import `full` from scrhelp.

Comment: ```import scrhelp
from scrhelp import *
print(scrhelp.full)
``` This works thank you! I can only accept your answer in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do a simple example:

```
class CoolClass():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.cool_variable = "test"
        

TestClass = CoolClass()
print(TestClass.cool_variable)
#out: test

TestClass.cool_variable = "new value"
print(TestClass.cool_variable)
#out: new value
```

**init** method is executed the moment you create an object from the class.
This means you can seta variable like this and get the value by writing: ObjectName.variablename as in the example. Of course you can also modify it inside the class or as shown in the example outside the class.

This works therefore for classes which you import as well.